# How to Import JSON file in ES5?

Tags: javascript, json, import, ecmascript-5

I have JSON file name `data.json` having data as

```
{
   "name":"XYZ"
}
```

and I have one ES5 file name `script.js` in which I want to use this JSON file and the task is to import the file and store the data in the init function in the ES5 class.
I have tried

`var data =  require('./data.json')` 
It gives me

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: Are you sure you are **NOT** running this on a browser/client side?

Comment: Yes, I'm running it, I have added a script.js in index.html

Comment: then what is the solution if I do run in browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `data.json` file like this

```
data={
   "name":"XYZ"
}
```

and import the data.json file into the index.html so that data.json stay upper then script.js

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

now you can use `data` as a variable in the script.js

Answer (score 4):

Referring to the comments on this post;

You are currently running your snippet in the browser and using CommonJS imports.
Browsers use ES6 imports:

```
import * as data from "./data.json"
```

For further references:
MDN on modules: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Freecodebootcamp: [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc/)